# Logo in python shell

Tags: python-idle, graphical-logo

I have just been learning tkinter and I found out that you can change the logo with a custom one.

After doing this I started to wonder if there is any way to change the logo in the python shell.

I use idle 3.5 not python 2 or 3.

Thanks

Comment: IDLE 3.5 is the stdib app in Lib/idlelib running on Python 3.5. If by 'logo' you mean the icon on the window title bar, it is actually a downsized Python logo. The image files for *nix and Windows are in the Icons subdirectory. Since just a few years ago, they are used to replace the tkinter icon. For 3.5, the code is in PyShell.py. I do not understand 'cumson'. A typo?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that 'cumson' was probably meant to be 'custom'.  As I said in the comment, the Python/IDLE icon *is* a replacement.  You just have to replace the replacement.  The code and the image file format depend on the OS and python version.  From `idlelib/pyshell.py`:

```
# set application icon
icondir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Icons')
if system() == 'Windows':
    iconfile = os.path.join(icondir, 'idle.ico')
    root.wm_iconbitmap(default=iconfile)
else:
    ext = '.png' if TkVersion >= 8.6 else '.gif'
    iconfiles = [os.path.join(icondir, 'idle_%d%s' % (size, ext))
                 for size in (16, 32, 48)]
    icons = [PhotoImage(master=root, file=iconfile)
             for iconfile in iconfiles]
    root.wm_iconphoto(True, *icons)
```

Any change you make would have to be repeated for each installation or update of Python, as your replacement file would be overridden.